# bootstrap 4 css is not working with mail html template in flask

Tags: html, css, flask

so i have this html template that i am using as mail template to send my users for reset their password's. i want to use `bootstrap 4 classes` in the template but it's not working. How do i make this work ? I've tried `inline css` and it works fine but i want to use `bootstrap 4 css`. Any help would be appreciated.

**HTML template**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{{title}}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&family=Rubik:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>


    <div class="container">
        <div class="text-center">
            <h2>Have you just requested for the password reset !</h2>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-success">Reset Password</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Flask Code**

```
@app.route('/forget', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def forget_password():
    form = ForgetPassword()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template("forget.html", title="Forget Password", form=form)
    email = request.form['email']
    session['email'] = email
    token = s.dumps(email, salt='reset-password')
    msg = Message("Password Reset", sender="bookverm1999@gmail.com", recipients=[email])
    link = url_for("reset_pass", token=token, _external=True)
    msg.body = "Password Reset Link"
    msg.html = render_template("mail.html", link=link, title="Password Reset")
    mail.send(msg)
    return render_template("sent.html", title="Email Sent")
```

Comment: This css work in normal html that is in browser

Comment: what you mean ??

Comment: Did you try running your html file as a seperate file in Chrome or Firefox

Comment: yeah, and it worked fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use inline css, email doesen't support css linking, it is only supported by browsers.
I already tried to do that with an old css i created some time ago but i had to embed it in the html.