# Unable to make bootstrap cdn css work on HTML sent via outlook email

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using below bootstrap CDN for css styles.

```
   <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

They worked perfectly on plain HTML file and complete css applied, but when I send HTML file over outlook email, CSS styles didn't applied.

HTML file also includes DIV's.

From the below post, I can understand that Bootstrap CDN won't work for HTML sent via email.

[bootstrap 4 css is not working with mail html template in flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61500245/bootstrap-4-css-is-not-working-with-mail-html-template-in-flask)

Then, how can I include the above bootstrap cdn css in my html file itself as inline.

Pls suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Inline CSS is when you use the `style` attribute in HTML like this:

```html
<h1 style="color:red;">My Title</h1>
```

So email **only** supports this sort of CSS. You **cannot** use any `<link>` tags to include external sources of CSS, and its generally [not a good](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2105963/9063935) a good idea to do so.

If really want to you've got a couple of options.

1. Write it yourself
2. Try an "inliner" tool, such as these from [Mailchimp](https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/) and [Campaign Monitor](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/tools/css-inliner/), or [Premailer](https://premailer.io/)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use inline styles, css won't work for you. at this point you should install bootstrap instead of importing it with the cdn